# How to do four-coordinate non-projective image transformation in Java?

Tags: java, image, transformation

I'd like to transform a `BufferedImage` in Java, from a rectangle to an arbitrary convex quadrilateral, similarly to this:

[image]

But instead of using projective transformation, I'd like to simply use a linear transform that stretches and squeezes the image where appropriate, according to four coordinates that I want the corners of the final image to be.

What is the way to do this in Java?

edit: It seems that one solution is to draw a textured Quad in GL, which is deformed as I wish, using JOGL. I'm not sure about the support and efficiency, will investigate further.

Comment: I'd like at least an explanation for the downvotes, what is wrong with my question? I looked on SO and Google and I didn't find an answer :(

Comment: Forget about hit&run downvoters, they are the worst. You may want to take a look to the [Hello Texture](https://github.com/elect86/helloTriangle) sample of mine

Comment: thanks for the response, I ended up doing it like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing my own class in JOGL that turns the `BufferedImage` into a `Texture`, maps it on a quad, and renders it into an `OffscreenAutoDrawable`. Finally, that can be turned into a `BufferedImage` using `AWTGLReadBufferUtil.readPixelsToBufferedImage()`.